# Does the Python license allow to post modified versions of their source code on StackOverflow?

Tags: derivative-works, cc-by-sa, python

I just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60740375/3767239) on Stack Overflow which is largely based on a [specific part](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da1fe768e582387212201ab8737a1a5f26110664/Lib/inspect.py#L2889) of a module in the CPython standard library. The [Python license](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/LICENSE) seems to be permissive and they also indicate compatibility with GPL but since code posted on Stack Overflow is automatically [licensed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) under CC-BY-SA, I'm not sure if these two are compatible.

After reading the following two questions about derivative works of Python source code I'm inclined to believe it's no problem, but both answers also indicate that they prefer to release derivative work under the original license (which seems to conflict with the fact that Stack Overflow content is CC-BY-SA automatically).

- [Copyright of modifications and derivative works of Python License 2 licensed software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/8968/7904)
- [License for Python module derived from standard library module](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4335/7904)

So to summarize my question, I copied a portion of the CPython standard library source code, modified it slightly to my needs and included the modified version in one of my answers on Stack Overflow. Is that allowed per the Python license or does it cause a conflict?

Comment: 1. Technically you are already violating the Python license, because the license requires that you include the license terms along with your derivative work and the copyright notice, but you did not do that (nor does a site like StackOverflow practically allow such a thing in the post). 2. Most likely the license violation does not matter because you are presuming that this snippet is a fair use or fair dealing, and does not actually count as a "derivative work" as you think. However, only a court can generally decide this kind of thing.